# Will this battery case be able to sustain 3.5 amps?

Tags: current, heat, amperage

I'm trying to make a 10S Li-Ion battery case, and I'm currently wondering if it will be able to sustain a current of 3.5 amps running through it.

I like to believe I'm pretty good at electricity, however, I have no idea how much current can go through this thin plating (see picture).

[image: Nickel strip]

I'm looking to add nickel strips between the battery connectors, in order to connect the 10 cells in series. The nickel strips are 5mm wide and 0.2mm thick.

I wanted to solder the plates to the connectors using 63/37 tin/lead solder.

The 3.5 amps calculation comes from the fact that there will be 2 of these (10S2P) powering a 250 W device (at 36 V, so 250 W / 36 V = 7 A, 7 A /  2 = 3.5 A)

Is this doable? If not, what can I do to make it work? I may be able to stack several of the nickel plates together, if that may help. I can also put the plates inside the U shape of the spring contacts.

Thanks.

Comment: Questionable. I would suspect the spring contact will run hot.

Comment: @winny Do you think putting the nickle plates inside the spring contacts and filling them with solder would be enough?

Comment: The spring contacts should be fine, but the 5mm wide nickel straps might be a problem. I use desoldering braid saturated in solder (to stop it from fraying). Much lower resistance than nickel straps of the same size, and easier to solder. http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/straps.html

Answer (score 1):

This should actually be a comment, but it's too long

Sorry, but we have no idea how tight your contacts will be a) in the beginning b) after an year and numerous knocks. I guess the metal pieces itself have resistances only milliohms, but loose contact can get hot even at 3,5A. The only way to be sure is to make a test.

Note: if your battery pack gets some strong knocks your metal stripes can get bent and the contact can become loose. In addition solder can get broken. Mechanical strength under knocks and vibration should not be based on solder.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way I can make it secure (maybe overly so)? Additionally, how would I go about testing this? I don't have a huge resistor nor thermal equipment. I can, however, tell you that the contacts are currently EXTREMELY tight. It's hard to push a battery in, and pushing it out requires a screwdriver to act as a prying tool.

Comment: Make a dummy battery which has exact dimensions. Push it against the spring as strongly as needed to make the battery move as much as it can move before meeting a hard stop. release the dummy and take it off. Are the springs still at the original distance from each other? This reveals do you really have springs or plastic contact plates which get deformed. You can well test the heatening with a dummy and an external power supply. But you must have that 3,5A.

Comment: They do come back to their original position. If the contact is constantly maintained, is it safe to use it for 3.5A? (It'll never go above)

Comment: As already said, test with the real current. You must have it to know. It can come elsewhere than from a battery but it must be 3,5A. BTW the cooling must be the same than in the final compilation and you must keep it on until the temperature has settled. Otherwise there's no knowledge.